# Calling a C# library function with out parameters in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

If I have a C# function with an out parameter, I cannot get the out parameter when called from javascript.  Is this possible?

For example...

```
public class Test
{
   public bool function doSomething(string txt, out string retTxt)
   {
      ...
      retTxt = "some return value";
      return true;
   }
}
```

Javascript code..

```
   var outStr;
   var ret = testInstance.doSomething("instr", outStr);
```

Comment: I don't think JavaScript supports output parameters.

Comment: @David, All you have to do is pass in an object, which can be modified by the function.

Answer (score 1):

The [official msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) defines out parameter modifier as "causing arguments to be passed by reference".  Passing by reference would mean that you are passing the memory location of the variable, which would be impossible in a client/server situation.

Comment: It might not necessarily be a client/server situation.  It could be a C# library being used by JavaScript code in a Windows Store App, for example.

Comment: true, but even in that situation, the C# library and the JavaScript library aren't sharing memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

Out parameters used in this fashion is not a good idea. If you call a method you would expect it to do its job, if it can't it should throw, however if you really need that `bool` then you can wrap your output into a class and return that. In this case you can use an anonymous type if your using dot net 4.0 or later.

```
public class Test
{
   public object doSomething(string txt)
   {
      ...
      return new 
      {
          text = "some return value",
          success = true
      };
   }
}


var result = testInstance.doSomething("instr");
//    result.text
//    result.success
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, although we can't return anonymous type because of strong typing, I decided to defined the type.